# Swift 4 - Jumper Game Scoring

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have code in place for the scoring in a jumper game that I am creating. The score increases as the player moves up the screen. This code below works fine for keeping track of the score but the resulting Int is very high. Thus, a high score would result in the millions. I am trying to figure out how to divide the scoring increments, so that a high score would result in the thousands instead of the millions.

In line two, I tried putting `/ 2` after after `...position.y`, but that resulted in an extremely low negative Int.

Any suggestions?

```
if Int(player.position.y) > maxPlayerY! {
    GameState.sharedInstance.score += Int(player.position.y) - maxPlayerY!

    maxPlayerY = Int(player.position.y)

    scoreLabel.text = String(format: "Score: %d", GameState.sharedInstance.score)
}
```

Comment: Can't you replace the - maxPlayerY with something else to alter the number? I.e. put your divide here?

Comment: You could keep your scoring as it is now internally, and just scale it when you update the scoreLabel: `scoreLabel.text = String(format: "Score: %d", GameState.sharedInstance.score / 100)`.  Try different divisors to see what feels right.

Comment: vacawama ... that worked. Thanks.